# How to get a single item across many sites in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this situation:

I want to crawl products details from a specific product detail page which describes the product (Page A), this page contains a link to a page that list sellers of this product (Page B), in  each seller is a link to another page (Page C) which contains seller details, here is an example schema:

Page A:

- product_name
- link to sellers of this product (Page B)

Page B:

- list of sellers, each one containing:

  - seller_name
  - selling_price
  - link to the seller details page (Page C)

Page C:

- seller_address

This is the json I want to obtain after crawling:

```
{
  "product_name": "product1",
  "sellers": [
    {
      "seller_name": "seller1",
      "seller_price": 100,
      "seller_address": "address1",
    },
    (...)
  ]
}
```

What I have tried: passing the product information from  in parse method to second parse method in meta object, this works fine on 2 levels, but I have 3, and I want a single item.

Is this possible in scrapy?

EDIT:

as requested here is a minified example of what I am trying to do, I know it wont work as expected, but I can not figure out how to make it return only 1 composed object:

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'examplespider'
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    start_urls = [
        'http://example.com/products/product1'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        # assume this object was obtained after
        # some xpath processing
        product_name = 'product1'
        link_to_sellers = 'http://example.com/products/product1/sellers'

        yield scrapy.Request(link_to_sellers, callback=self.parse_sellers, meta={
            'product': {
                'product_name': product_name,
                'sellers': []
            }
        })

    def parse_sellers(self, response):
        product = response.meta['product']

        # assume this object was obtained after
        # some xpath processing
        sellers = [
            {
                seller_name = 'seller1',
                seller_price = 100,
                seller_detail_url = 'http://example.com/sellers/seller1',
            },
            {
                seller_name = 'seller2',
                seller_price = 100,
                seller_detail_url = 'http://example.com/sellers/seller2',
            },
            {
                seller_name = 'seller3',
                seller_price = 100,
                seller_detail_url = 'http://example.com/sellers/seller3',
            }
        ]

        for seller in sellers:
            product['sellers'].append(seller)
            yield scrapy.Request(seller['seller_detail_url'], callback=self.parse_seller, meta={'seller': seller})

    def parse_seller(self, response):
        seller = response.meta['seller']

        # assume this object was obtained after
        # some xpath processing
        seller_address = 'seller_address1'

        seller['seller_address'] = seller_address

        yield seller
```

Comment: Post the code you have used.

Comment: I thought it was a common use case, but I will post some example code at night, thanks

Comment: code posted, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your logic a bit, so as it to query one seller address at a time only and once that completes you query other sellers.

```
def parse_sellers(self, response):
    meta = response.meta

    # assume this object was obtained after
    # some xpath processing
    sellers = [
        {
            seller_name = 'seller1',
            seller_price = 100,
            seller_detail_url = 'http://example.com/sellers/seller1',
        },
        {
            seller_name = 'seller2',
            seller_price = 100,
            seller_detail_url = 'http://example.com/sellers/seller2',
        },
        {
            seller_name = 'seller3',
            seller_price = 100,
            seller_detail_url = 'http://example.com/sellers/seller3',
        }
    ]

    current_seller = sellers.pop()
    if current_seller:
       meta['pending_sellers'] = sellers
       meta['current_seller'] = current_seller
       yield scrapy.Request(current_seller['seller_detail_url'], callback=self.parse_seller, meta=meta)
    else:
       yield product


    # for seller in sellers:
    #     product['sellers'].append(seller)
    #     yield scrapy.Request(seller['seller_detail_url'], callback=self.parse_seller, meta={'seller': seller})

def parse_seller(self, response):
    meta = response.meta
    current_seller = meta['current_seller']
    sellers = meta['pending_sellers']
    # assume this object was obtained after
    # some xpath processing
    seller_address = 'seller_address1'

    current_seller['seller_address'] = seller_address

    meta['product']['sellers'].append(current_seller)
    if sellers:
        current_seller = sellers.pop()
        meta['pending_sellers'] = sellers
        meta['current_seller'] = current_seller

        yield scrapy.Request(current_seller['seller_detail_url'], callback=self.parse_seller, meta=meta)
    else:
        yield meta['product']
```

But this is till not a great approach, reason being a seller may be selling multiple items. So when you reach the a item by same seller again then your request for seller address would get rejected by dupe filter. You can fix that by adding `dont_filter=True` to the request but that would mean too many unnecessary hits to the website

So you need to add DB handling directly in code to check if you already have a sellers details, if yes then use them, if not then you need fetch the details.

Answer (score 0):

I think a [pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) could help.

Assuming yielded `seller` is in the following format (which can be done by some trivial modification of the code):

```
seller = {
    'product_name': 'product1',
    'seller': {
        'seller_name': 'seller1',
        'seller_price': 100,
        'seller_address': 'address1',
    }
}
```

A pipeline like the following will collect sellers by their `product_name` and export to a file named 'items.jl' after crawling (Note this is just a sketch of the idea so it is not guaranteed to work):

```
class CollectorPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.collection = {}

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.collection = {}

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        with open("items.jl", "w") as fp:
            for _, product in self.collection.items():
                fp.write(json.dumps(product))
                fp.write("\n")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        product = self.collection.get(item["product_name"], dict())
        product["product_name"] = item["product_name"]
        sellers = product.get("sellers", list())
        sellers.append(item["seller"])

        return item
```

BTW your need to modify your `settings.py` to make the pipeline effective, as described in [scrapy document](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component).